# Reading Lines from Sample Code in 'Programming in Scala'

Tags: scala

Working through a sample in Chapter 3 of "Programming in Scala", the following code doesn't seem working on Scala 2.8:

```
import scala.io.Source

if (args.length > 0) {
    for (line <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines)
        print(line.length + " " + line)
}
else
    Console.err.println("Filename required.")
```

Scala complains `fromFile` is expecting type `java.io.File`.  With a bit of searching it seems that I should be using `fromPath` instead...

```
    for (line <- Source.fromPath(args(0)).getLines)
```

However, I now get a puzzling error from that (puzzling to a beginner anyways):

```
... :4: error: missing arguments for method getLines in class Source;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
    for (line <- Source.fromPath(args(0)).getLines)
                                          ^
one error found
```

I took a guess at trying...

```
    for (line <- Source.fromPath(args(0)).getLines _)
```

And that didn't work.  What's the Scala 2.8 way of making `getLines` work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732487/error-with-default-argument-in-source-getlines-scala-2-8-0-rc1

Comment: ah indeed, missed that one when answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of getLines is this:

```
def getLines(separator: String = compat.Platform.EOL): Iterator[String] = new LineIterator(separator)
```

So it has a default argument. You need to write `getLines()` instead, so that this default will be used.